# Jquery .css isn't working from within a function

Tags: jquery, css, function

I'm playing around with a little game in JQuery, and I need to change the css of buttons. I'm in the testing phase, so it's a bit unorganized at the moment.

Anyway, let's say I click on a button. This should make the text for that button change to the color red.
**THIS WORKS**

```
$(".btn-card").click(function(){
    $(this).css({"color":"red"});
});
```

Now let's say I pick a random button, and hard code this in, no where in particular. **THIS WORKS**

```
$(function(){
    var i = 5;
    $("#Card" + i).css({"color":"red"});
});
```

But now, let's say I take that same basic concept, and copy and paste it inside a function. **THIS DOES NOT WORK**

```
function enemyTurn(){ 
    highlightCard(5); 
}
function highlightCard(i){
    $("#Card" + i).css({"color":"red"});
}
```

Is there a reason why the **.css()** works in the other 2 examples, but not in the 3rd example?

**EDIT**
I need to be able to call the **function from anywhere in the code** not in the button.Click events

**EDIT** 
I think I figured out why it's not working. But I don't know how to explain it (clearly) so I'll edit this later once I get the solution working. 
Player = button clicks. (good) The Enemy's turn is based on code, not action. So the enemy cant perform a button click. A button click will act like a "refresh", that's why it's working. I need to be able to "refresh" the state of the page on the enemy's turn, without actually refreshing the page (which would do nothing). I just assumed that changing the css would actually change the css, but that technically isn't true.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it does not work?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Card5" onClick="testFunc()">Click me to change text color</button>
<script>
function highlightCard(i){
    $("#Card" + i).css({"color":"red"});
}
function testFunc(){
 highlightCard(5);
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="Card5">Test Button</button>
    <script>
    function highlightCard(i){
        $("#Card" + i).css({"color":"red"});
    }
//highlight button when page loads
     highlightCard(5);

    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="Card1">Test Button</button>
<button id="Card2">Test Button</button>
<button id="Card3">Test Button</button>
<button id="Card4">Test Button</button>
<button id="Card5">Test Button</button>
<button id="Card6">Test Button</button>
<button id="Card7">Test Button</button>
<button id="Card8">Test Button</button>
<br/>
Enter card number to select:<br/>
<input id="cardnum" type="text" onkeyup="selectcard()">
<br/>
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
var lastcardnum = null;
        function highlightCard(i){
            $("#Card" + i).css({"color":"red"});
        }
    function selectcard(){
       if(lastcardnum!=null){
        $('#Card'+lastcardnum).css({"color":"black"});
       }
      var $result = $("#result");
      var $cardnum = $("#cardnum").val();
      try{
      if($cardnum.trim().length&&!isNaN(parseInt($cardnum, 10))&&parseInt($cardnum, 10)<=8&&parseInt($cardnum, 10)>=1){
      highlightCard($cardnum);
      $result.html("Card "+$cardnum+" selected");
      lastcardnum = $cardnum;
    } else {
      $result.html("<b style='color: red;'>Card number must be a number from 1 to 8!</b>");
    }
    } catch(err){
     $result.html("<b style='color: red;'>Card number must be a number from 1 to 8!</b>");
    }
    }

 </script>
```

Comment: I need to be able to call the function from other functions.
The .click events are examples of what works. So yes, your example works. But that is an example of what I'm talking about. The click events work. The "enemy" cannot click on buttons. (Player vs Computer) Calling from a function does not work. I do not know why.

Comment: Yes, you see this still works.. but it does not work when called from within a function for whatever reason. function enemyTurn() { highlightCard(8); } will not highlight Card8.

Comment: @PixiiBomb Are you sure you have an element with an `id` of `Card8`?

Comment: Yes. I can access every single Button with the ID Card0 - Card19. I can do whatever I want with any of those IDs. I cannot (for whatever reason) change the css from within a function. function-inception isnt working

Comment: Are you sure the enemyTurn() function is called? Put console.log('enemy turn called') inside the function to see if it's called. Also, it'll be easier for people to help you if you write your pseudocode down: what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Why have you mixed so much JQuery and raw javascript in your answer....!? JQuery selectors immediately followed by `document.getElementById`. Using `elem.innerHtml` instead of `$(elem).html()` ... why!!!?

Comment: @Zze Yes, you are right. I have changed my code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet works for me, but I would suggest a different approach - have a highlight class with the {color: red} styling and then add / remove the class on click or on the function call. Far better to not alter css in the js function.

The following has a number of buttons with the function call as well as a click event handler to alter the color.

```js
$(".btn-card").click(function(){
  $('.btn-card').removeClass('highlight');
  $(this).addClass('highlight')
});



function highlightCard(i){
  $('.btn-card').removeClass('highlight');
  $("#Card" + i).addClass('highlight')
}

highlightCard(5);
```

```css
.highlight {color: red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" id ="Card1" class="btn btn default btn-card">Card 1</button>
<button type="button" id ="Card2" class="btn btn default btn-card">Card 2</button>
<button type="button" id ="Card3" class="btn btn default btn-card">Card 3</button>
<button type="button" id ="Card4" class="btn btn default btn-card">Card 4</button>
<button type="button" id ="Card5" class="btn btn default btn-card">Card 5</button>
<button type="button" id ="Card6" class="btn btn default btn-card">Card 6</button>
```